# React setState being overwritten within .map()

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-hooks, setstate, array.prototype.map

I am trying to dynamically fetch data from multiple endpoints and save to local state using React hooks. When I log the below, it looks like state is being overwritten for each item in `refDataArr`.

The data is being parsed and stored correctly, but I would like `refData` state to include all four results, and not be overwritten.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const refDataArr = [
      {
        url: "users",
        field: "user"
      },
      {
        url: "products",
        field: "product"
      },
      {
        url: "roles",
        field: "role"
      },
      {
        url: "locations",
        field: "location"
      }
    ]

    const fetchRefData = () => {
      console.log('Fetching reference data...');
      try {
        refDataArr.map(async (o, index) => {
          let url = o.url
          let field = o.field
          const res = await axios.get(`http://.../${url}/ `);
          const data = res.data.data

          let resArr = Object.values(data).map((item, index) => {
            return {
              key: item._key,
              value: item[field]
            }
          });
          setRefData({
            ...refData, 
            [field]: resArr, 
          })
        })
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
    fetchRefData();
  }, []);
```

Example log of result (other logs show users, roles, etc. They are being overwritten):

```
refData = {
 user: [
  {key: 1, value: "A"},
  {key: 2, value: "B"}
 ]
}

refData = {
 location: [
  {key: 1, value: "A"},
  {key: 2, value: "B"}
 ]
}

...etc
```

Desired result:

```
refData = {
 user: [
  {key: 1, value: "A"},
  {key: 2, value: "B"}
 ],
 product: [
  {key: 1, value: "A"},
  {key: 2, value: "B"}
 ],
 role: [
  {key: 1, value: "A"},
  {key: 2, value: "B"}
 ],
 location: [
  {key: 1, value: "A"},
  {key: 2, value: "B"}
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build your desired object and then after its completly built use the `setRefData` you need.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const refDataArr = [
      {
        url: "users",
        field: "user"
      },
      {
        url: "products",
        field: "product"
      },
      {
        url: "roles",
        field: "role"
      },
      {
        url: "locations",
        field: "location"
      }
    ]
    let newData = {};
    const fetchRefData = () => {
      console.log('Fetching reference data...');
      try {
        refDataArr.map(async (o, index) => {
          let url = o.url
          let field = o.field
          const res = await axios.get(`http://.../${url}/ `);
          const data = res.data.data

          let resArr = Object.values(data).map((item, index) => {
            return {
              key: item._key,
              value: item[field]
            }
          });
          newData = {...newData, [field]: [...resArr]}
        })
        setRefData({
          ...refData, 
          ...newData, 
        })
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
    fetchRefData();
  }, []);
```

Comment: If you could elaborate that would be helpful

Comment: Generate an object with your data. Then, save that object using the function `setRefData`